# Pytorch parameter matrix from loss function of transformation

Tags: pytorch

I have a pytorch tensor `k x (n+k-1)` tensor `w` with `requires_grad=True`. I want to transform it into a `kxn` tensor `p` also with as such: `p[i] = w[i][i:i+n]`. How do I do this, such that by calling `backward()` on a loss function of `p` in the end, I will learn `w`?

Answer (score 1):

Any sort of indexing operation would do, with the backward function being `<CopySlices>`
A naive way of doing this would be using simple python indexing:

```
w_unrolled = torch.zeros(p.size())
for i in range(w.shape[0]):
    w_unrolled[i] = w[i][i:i+n]
loss = criterion(w_unrolled, p)
```

You can then reduce your loss via mean/sum on whichever axis. Note that while this will work, it is inefficient; the optimal way would be to use a native indexing function to speed things up.